# MinGW annoying behavior, sometimes compiles, sometimes not?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, mingw, msys

I am compiling and debugging my little project with msys and MinGW. Sometimes, it compiles just fine but about 2/3 of time instead prints this error message:

```
include/player.h:1:0: fatal error: can't create precompiled header
bazglx.exe:invalid argument
compilation terminated.
make: *** [bazglx.exe] Error 1
```

The topmost line was in Finnish so I had to translate it and it may not be identical to English one. Here is my makefile:

```
CC = g++

IDIR = include
ODIR = obj
SDIR = src


CFLAGS = -I $(IDIR) -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wall -ggdb
LFLAGS = -lSDL_gfx

_OBJ = main.o init.o mainloop.o render.o map.o player.o
_DEPS = init.h mainloop.h render.h map.h player.h

OBJ = $(patsubst %.o, $(ODIR)/%.o, $(_OBJ))
DEPS = $(patsubst %.h, $(IDIR)/%.h, $(_DEPS))

$(ODIR)/%.o:$(SDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ `sdl-config --cflags` $(CFLAGS) -c

bazglx.exe:$(OBJ) $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ `sdl-config --libs --cflags` $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
```

Sometimes it even displays the error message but creates a corrupt exe. There is nothing special at the start of the file it blames and the it has even blamed other files. This is really confusing and annoying and really slowing down my progress.

Comment: I'm not sure what this means.  Can you check your disk space and make sure you have enough?  Also, if you set the environment variable `LANG` to the value `C` it will print all messages in English.

Comment: I certainly have enought space, program is not big. And I got the English message and it is identical.

Comment: I'd change to `SDL_CFLAGS := $(shell sdl-config --cflags)` and `SDL_LDFLAGS := $(shell sdl-config --libs)`. Then `CFLAGS := ... $(SDL_CFLAGS)` and `LDFLAGS := ... $(SDL_LDFLAGS)`. And then use only `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` down the road. Furthermore, move `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` to `LDFLAGS` as these are really flags for linking, **not** compilation, and remove `CFLAGS` from the linking stage, i.e. only leave `LDFLAGS` on the last line.

Comment: Finally, prefer `:=` over `=` as it is what you want most of the time. Refer to Make documentation to learn about differences between them. There are quite some pitfalls associated with `=`. Last but not least, think about learning and switching to some modern build system such as **[CMake](http://www.cmake.org/)**, for example, rather than using bare Make. Leave make for 80's - 90's, today people don't build complex software with bare Make anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This rule is wrong:

```
bazglx.exe:$(OBJ) $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ `sdl-config --libs --cflags` $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
```

It causes `$(CC)` to be invoked with the list of header files as inputs in addition to the object files.  The compiler will try to precompile the headers into the output file `bazglx.exe` (one-after the other, each time overwriting the one before), then it will link the object files into the output file (overwriting it again) to produce the output.

You want your link step to involve only the object files and the libraries.

I suspect that you're getting an error (and only getting it sometimes) because something is preventing GCC from opening the `bazglx.exe` file when it's trying to precompile `include/player.h`. You can see a similar effect (though with probably with a different error on the second line) if you type the following command in yourself:

```
g++ include/player.h -o some-non-directory/bazglx.exe
```

Maybe an antivirus is opening and processing the repeated new instances of `bazglx.exe`, and sometimes that processing isn't done before GCC wants to recreate it?

Comment: It's usually a good idea to tell your antivirus not to scan files in folders where you'll be compiling your own code. The antivirus scanning your newly compiled programs has little if any benefit, it just slows things down and occasionally causes problems. I once managed to get a false positive in one of my programs, and the antivirus had been told to silently remove such files - I spent an age trying to figure out why I was compiling but there was no binary.